# how to show 'coming soon' message on category pages

Tags: category

I am working on a project where client wants to have 'coming soon' message on some category pages. I am not sure how to put this message.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put a particular message on the selected category page, follow below apporach:

1) Create a static block with your message ie: "Coming Soon"

2) Goto to the Category on which you need to display the message

3) Goto Display Settings tab and select Display Mode = "Static Blocks Only"

4) Select Static Block which you created and save the settings.

**EDIT**

In case you want just the blank page without menu, you will have to create a new template file say `categorylanding.phtml`  and call it in the design tab. Follow below procedure to do so.

1) Goto app/design/frontend/Yourtheme/template/page and create a new file named `categorylanding.phtml` (Create a copy of `empty.phtml`)

2) Enter all the required elements from other layout files.

3) Goto Category>>Custom Design>>Custom Layout Updates

4) Add below XML code to call the template file.

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/categorylanding.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: But this option will also show the menu. He doesn't want to have menu also only blank page with message.

Comment: Please check the edit